# jquery draggable/droppable update database with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, draggable, droppable

I have draggable divs that are created with a php loop grabbing info from a MYSQL database. code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".box").draggable({revert:true});
        $("#trashcan").droppable({
            hoverClass: 'border',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

PHP/HTML

```
<?php
//display boxes
    while ($list = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

?>
        <a href="<?php echo $list['url'];?>">
            <div class="box"><h2><?php echo $list['label'];?></h2>
            </div>
       </a>
    <?php };?>

<div id="trashcan" >
  <p>Trash</p>
</div>
```

My question is: how can I get the PHP variable $list['label'] to be sent by Jquery as an ajax call so that I can make a revision to a MYSQL database (i.e. delete the record) after the draggable is accepted by the droppable div?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the ajax call in the `drop` function

Comment: Thanks, but how do I grab $list['label'] and send it via ajax with Jquery?

Comment: `$(ui.draggable).find("h2").text()`

Comment: Thanks, that grabs it but how do I send it?